# Spark dataframe string to month

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe where one column `orddate` as string, and I want to extract months from the `orddate`, make a new column with `month` name on new df.

```
|orddate|
|12/1/10 9:37| 
|20/3/10 10:37| 
|09/8/14 4:56| 
|30/12/11 12:13| 
|24/5/10 7:27|
```

convert to

```
|orddate| month |
|12/1/10 9:37| january|
|20/3/10 10:37| march |
|09/8/14 4:56| august |
|30/12/11 12:13| december |
|24/5/10 7:27| may |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) use `unix_timestamp` with format `dd/MM/yy hh:mm` to convert the column to time stamp; 
2) use `from_unixtime` with format `MMMMM` to convert the time stamp to `month`;

You can see more about the format [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{from_unixtime, unix_timestamp}

df.withColumn("month", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp($"orddate", "dd/MM/yy hh:mm"), "MMMMM")).show

+--------------+--------+
|       orddate|   month|
+--------------+--------+
|  12/1/10 9:37| January|
| 20/3/10 10:37|   March|
|  09/8/14 4:56|  August|
|30/12/11 12:13|December|
|  24/5/10 7:27|     May|
+--------------+--------+
```